# Run Jenkins jobs on Linux under a User

Tags: linux, jenkins

I have Jenkins installed in Linux and I want to run the build(s) under a user.

Not just a simple user, but one that belongs to the list of user that access the linux machine and that belongs to a certain group as it has privileges to modify/create files under a certain folder.

I have read somewhere that you can set the variable $JENKINS_USER but I do not know where and how.
 Thank you for your time

P.S. I did some research all the questions posted are similar but not the same as this one

Please if I am not clear read this:
Usually Jenkins execute the build using a user called jenkins, now I want to be able to use a different user (pre-existing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the Started-By Environment Variable plugin.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Started-By+Environment+Variable+Plugin

EDIT:

If you are just asking how to set up Jenkins to run under a different user in Linux it depends on how you installed it. I never set up Jenkins on Linux yet (but I can use google). Have a look at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins for different setup options. I had a look at [Installing Jenkins as a Unix daemon](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Unix+daemon) and at step 7 you need to setup a configuration file. Change the last line in that file (`RUN_AS_USER=jenkins`) to contain the user of your choice.

Comment: I am having a look, but that set an environment variable to the name of the user that started the build, like in jenkins the user jenkins runs the build and all that crap, I'd like to set another user to do that

Comment: After you have the user name, you can run scripts with `su` (unix/linux) or runas (windows). --- After reading your question again, I am wondering whether you just want to run Jenkins under a different user account and not just a few jobs.

Comment: Hi Peter, I was reading the Unix Deamon guide I saw the configuration file and the script, maybe I should do it in that way. I think you exactly capture what I want.. run Jenkins under a different user account, is that possible? if yes, how :(:(?

Comment: Since I don't know how you installed your Jenkins (e.g. do you use an App server?). In general, it looks like you need to find the right config file and change "jenkins" to whatever you want. Or just create a user called jenkins and and add it to the appropriate groups. :) If you just use the jenkins user, then you always now what is Jenkins fault.

Comment: Hi Paul :) Thanks, well, I have it installed on Linux with no app Server (I simply installed it using the rpm package) I tried to change the jenkins user but unfortunately when I tried to start the jenkins it wasn't working as in Jenkins wasn't loading at all :(

Comment: Ps. Sorry I called you Paul, I meant Peter :(

Comment: Sorry, have only the standard troubleshooting tips as an help for you. In your case: What is the difference between the two users? Easiest way would be to just go with the Jenkins user and add him to the needed groups.

Comment: yup, that is what I did, I have sorted, I think I will write a question and answer so that everyone will know about it

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is necessary to set JENKINS_USER variable, but in another file.

Look here http://blog.manula.org/2013/03/running-jenkins-under-different-user-in.html

Comment: dont run jenkins as root if your encounter rights issues on files when running jobs. You know, deep down, its wrong. But it seems so quickly done like that. NO. Dont.

Comment: @yfhrpcx What alternative is there, then, if I need Jenkins to do things that I would be doing as root user??

Comment: I would not recommend that, see @yfhrpcx comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48021229/615312)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing only the root user could do that you cant do in a proper way, by creating a dedicated user for your task with proper rights on the concerned files or binaries. Give example of the task you want to do as root if you need more accurate example.

Comment: Well, after 5 years I came up with the solution (see above) in the then organization I worked for we had a specific user for jenkins jobs. Jenkins jobs were mainly for SCM, such user had the right roles and credentials to carry out each job.

Comment: Oh oups, this answer were supposed to be the answer of @Amalgovinus comment in previous post.