# How to trigger downstream Jenkins builds when using pre-shell steps

Tags: ruby, shell, maven, jenkins

I have a Maven Jenkins job that I want to trigger from another job - as a downstream job - as well as be able to start the job manually.

Manual trigger works fine but I noticed that when the job is triggered from another job a lot of the environment is lost. Basic commands can no longer be executed.

For example Maven/Jenkins uses `uname` for some purpose. The log then shows

```
/usr/local/maven-3.2.5/bin/mvn: 1: /usr/local/maven-3.2.5/bin/mvn: uname: not found
```

It is the same for Ruby. The job runs fine when triggered manually. When triggered from another job Ruby no longer exists.

I didn't expect a big difference in functionality of Jenkins depending on manual or automatic trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check which user runs Jenkins for you. Is this on a *nix machine? Setup bashrc/bash_profile etc. to setup the environment for Jenkins functional user. Add some paths to env PATH to be able to use tools (Ruby etc.).

[Managing Jenkins functional user](http://blog.manula.org/2013/03/running-jenkins-under-different-user-in.html) described thoroughly here. [Even more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910075/run-jenkins-jobs-on-linux-under-a-user).

Comment: This was caused by me using `path` as a variable. This causes the system `path` to be changed. Didn't realize that Jenkins was using ordinary environment variables to pass parameters.

Comment: I guess you can count my answer as helpful, then? ;)