# Nuget Push returns 403 after publishing to Artifactory through Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, nuget, nuget-package, artifactory, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to push my nuget package to artifactory. The commands to do that are embedded in my msbuild file. When I run the commands directly or through the msbuild file on my local machine / jenkins agent machine, I am able to push the package successfully.

But when the same msbuild file is executed using jenkins pipeline, even though the package get pushed to artifactory, I get the response as "Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden)" and the hence the build fails.

Can anyone help here?

Comment: What do you see in Artifactory's request.log after the build fails? If the issue is related to Artifactory then it has to be listed in request.log.

Answer (score 1):

Seems a bit strange that you get a 403 *and* it works but it sounds like an issue with the effective user that the Jenkins job is running under. On Windows you can amend the user by changing it on the Jenkins windows service, I haven't used Jenkins on other OSs but the answer on
[Run Jenkins jobs on Linux under a User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910075/run-jenkins-jobs-on-linux-under-a-user) have some pointers about doing the same for Linux.

Obviously in either case make sure your Jenkins user has necessary permissions to push to Artifactory.

Comment: I am using it on windows. The jenkins job is running under a service account and I am setting the api key for the same service account before pushing the package to nuget. The service account has deploy permission on the folder in artifactory. Is there any other permission which needs to be set?

Comment: As @Ariel says above, you should confirm this is an Artifactory issue, if you're you could post some of the jenkins console log or narrow down the smallest job that gives you the same issue to track the problem down.